# total resistance of sector of cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance

I have sector of cylinder with inner radius $r_1$ and outer radius of $r_2$
[image]

Now, the current goes through inner radius surface to outer radius surface, it has resistivity $\rho$, and has thickness of cylinder $h$
From the top view, it looks like below.

[image]

Its central angle is $\frac{2\pi}{n}$.

Now I want to calculate the total resistance of this sector(is this how we call this figure?), what I did was

$$
dR=\rho\frac{dr}{A}=\rho\frac{dr}{h2\pi r/n}
$$
$$
R_{tot}=\frac{n\rho}{2\pi h}\int^{r_2}_{r_1}\frac{1}{r}dr
=\frac{n\rho}{2\pi h}\ln\left(\frac{r_2}{r_1}\right)
$$

Is this correct?

---

Moreover, it was sheet resistance $R_s$. Can I replace this with resistivity  $\rho=h\times R_s$?

Comment: Appears correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way to calculate the resistance and your answer are correct. In this formula you can also express resistivity by [sheet resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheet_resistance) $\rho = h \cdot R_\mathrm{s}$.